# drop rows with multiple conditions in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

1. List item

Raw text of data:
;pclass;survived;sex;age;sibsp;parch;ticket;fare;cabin;embarked;boat;body;homedest;case_id;names

0;1;0.0;male;67;1;0;PC 17483;2.217.792;C55 C57;S;;96.0;New York, NY;1;Straus, Mr. Isidor

1;1;0.0;male;46;0;0;694;26.0;;S;;80.0;Bennington, VT;2;Jones, Mr. Charles Cresson

2;1;0.0;male;50;1;0;PC 17761;106.425;C86;C;;62.0;Deephaven, MN / Cedar Rapids, IA;3;Douglas, Mr. Walter Donald

3;1;0.0;male;61;0;0;36963;323.208;D50;S;;46.0;Haddenfield, NJ;4;Sutton, Mr. Frederick

4;1;0.0;male;32,5;0;0;113503;211.5;C132;C;;45.0;;5;Keeping, Mr. Edwin

[a picture of some of the DF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WGDeX.png)

I wan't to drop rows with multiple conditions in a pandas dataframe, both conditions are text and the dtype is object.

I tried this:

```
full_dataset_withNames = pd.read_csv('full_dataset_with_names.csv',sep=';')

df_new = full_dataset_withNames.drop(full_dataset_withNames[(full_dataset_withNames['sex'] == 'male') & (full_dataset_withNames['age'] == 'NaN')].index)
```

But no rows has been removed.

Comment: please provide a sample DF

Comment: I have taken a picture of some of it. Is it enough?

Comment: There are probably no matching rows. Try `((full_dataset_withNames['sex'] == 'male') & (full_dataset_withNames['age'] == 'NaN')).any(axis=1).sum()`. If the output is 0, no condition is satisfied.

Comment: @user19774705. No it's not enough. Provide your data as raw text.  Use something like `full_dataset_withNames.head(20)`

Comment: It gives this error:
ValueError: No axis named 1 for object type <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>

I can see fin the file that there are multiple places where is says both male and NaN.

Comment: How should I take the data in as raw text? I am sorry I have not tried to ask in here before. 
I have copied some of the top from the csv file in the question now.

Comment: In the raw data it is just a empty spot where it shows NaN in the dataframe. I have tried to replace NaN with just '' that did not work. Do you know how to find the empty spot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use "isna" method to check for NaN values

```
mask = (full_dataset_withNames['sex'] == 'male') & (full_dataset_withNames['age'].isna())
df_new = full_dataset_withNames.drop(full_dataset_withNames[mask].index)
```